# Jest: how to abort async test on timeout?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

My Jest test has a timeout configured. My test performs potentially long-running work. I want the code to abort when Jest times out. How do I do that?

Here's the code:

```js
describe('timeout', () => {
    jest.setTimeout(1000);

    test('timeout', async () => {
        // Emulates long-running work
        await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));

        // Follow-up work after long-running work
        expect(true).toBeTruthy();
        console.log('waited 2s');
    });
});
```

When Jest times out after 1s, I want everything after "Follow-up work after long-running work" to not be executed. How do I do that? Is there a way to ask Jest whether the timeout has been reached?

Current behavior of above code:

```
 FAIL  timeout.test.js
  timeout
    ✕ timeout (1002 ms)

  ● timeout › timeout

    thrown: "Exceeded timeout of 1000 ms for a test.
    Use jest.setTimeout(newTimeout) to increase the timeout value, if this is a long-running test."

      2 |     jest.setTimeout(1000);
      3 |
    > 4 |     test('timeout', async () => {
        |     ^
      5 |         // Emulates long-running work
      6 |         await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));
      7 |

      at timeout.test.js:4:5
      at Object.<anonymous> (timeout.test.js:1:83)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.197 s, estimated 2 s
Ran all test suites matching timeout.test.js/i.

  ●  Cannot log after tests are done. Did you forget to wait for something async in your test?
    Attempted to log "waited 2s".

       8 |         // Follow-up work after long-running work
       9 |         expect(true).toBeTruthy();
    > 10 |         console.log('waited 2s');
         |                 ^
      11 |     });
      12 | });
      13 |

      at console.log (node_modules/@jest/console/build/CustomConsole.js:187:10)
      at Object.<anonymous> (timeout.test.js:10:17)
```

Desired behavior:

```
 FAIL  timeout.test.js
  timeout
    ✕ timeout (1002 ms)

  ● timeout › timeout

    thrown: "Exceeded timeout of 1000 ms for a test.
    Use jest.setTimeout(newTimeout) to increase the timeout value, if this is a long-running test."

      2 |     jest.setTimeout(1000);
      3 |
    > 4 |     test('timeout', async () => {
        |     ^
      5 |         // Emulates long-running work
      6 |         await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));
      7 |

      at timeout.test.js:4:5
      at Object.<anonymous> (timeout.test.js:1:83)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.197 s, estimated 2 s
Ran all test suites matching timeout.test.js/i.
(no warnings after this)
```

Comment: This is going to be bad, bad test. You probably should re-consider what/how you're testing, otherwise you'll get some false-positive tests

Comment: Usually when timers are used in the implementation you can use [jest's fake timers](https://jestjs.io/docs/timer-mocks) to have the result without actually having to await for the actual timeout

Comment: Does it really matter to you if it fails with two error messages? Having both error messages gives you enough information to figure out what went wrong. Test timeouts are there to catch "runaway" tests, which are broken tests. If you actually want to test a specific timeout, you probably want to mock that / use fake timers.

Comment: There is probably no way to stop the execution flow of the test, except to throw an error in it / reject + return.

Comment: I'm not *actually* performing a sleep in my test. My test performs an HTTP POST which could potentially take seconds. I just want the test to stop if it notices that the POST has talen longer than expected, instead of keep running.

Comment: @Elias I know how to stop. But I want to detect *when* to stop. How do I know when the Jest timeout has passed?

Comment: @Hongli I don't think you can stop at a particular line without manually throwing an error. Everything external (asynchronous) would run after the function has finished.

Answer (score 0):

An async test can be aborted by throwing an error. Instead of relying on Jest to interrupt and abort your test function, you do it yourself by keeping track of the timeout.

The test basically becomes something like:

```
test("timeout", async() => {
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => { throw new Error("Test timed out") }, 5000)
    <your test code>

    clearTimeout(timeout)
})
```

the `clearTimeout` at the end is needed, otherwise the test will wait for the timeout to fire.